# Getting "This page isn’t working <url> redirected you too many times." error in production next.js middleware

Tags: cookies, next.js, middleware

So I'm trying to route my users to a sign in page if they don't have a cookie. My `_middleware.js` file looks like this:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(req, res) {
  const cookie = req.cookies['admin_cookie'];

  if ((req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/Submissions') || req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/Batches')) && cookie !== 'cookie_password') {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/Auth/', req.url));
  }
}
```

It works fine in development, but when I push to production (using vercel) I get the `redirected you too many times` error. Also yes I know that's not great security, it doesn't really matter for this project.

Comment: Could have many things. But here some points to check. 1 -  if login route is wrapped in this middleware; 2 - if admin_cookie never gets a valid value;

Comment: If you can run development build into production server, can presents you pitfalls, before build production bundle

Comment: @AloisoJunior I removed all mentions of '/Auth' route in middleware and instead changed it to be if path is /Submissions and cookie !== cookie password, redirect. Issue persists. I've updated my original question with the new simplified code that still gives the error

Comment: Can you show us the code for the `/Auth` route?